# Can we prove existence of Spectral Decomposition from Singular Value Decomposition(SVD)??

Tags: linear-algebra

The Spectral Decomposition Theorem is, if $A$ is hermitian , then there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that

$$U^{*}AU=D $$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

By using the existence of SVD, can we prove that Spectral Decomposition exists as well.